# Использование XML атрибутов в собственной конфигурации Logback

Tags: java, xml, config, logback

Для конфигурации разрабатываемого Appender'а для Logback используется XML узел *appender*. На данный момент (и во всех найденных примерах) для конфигурации используются только XML-узлы и их текстовые значения, т.е. без атрибутов самих узлов.

Вопрос: как настроить/сконфигурировать/реализовать поддержку маппинга атрибутов XML-узла с соответствующим свойством?

Пробовал использовать аннотацию `@XmlAttribute(name = "level")` для сеттера/геттера/поля, но это ни коим образом не помогает.

Ниже приведён пример используемого кода.

###### logback.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" xmlns="http://ch.qos.logback/xml/ns/logback"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://ch.qos.logback/xml/ns/logback https://raw.githubusercontent.com/enricopulatzo/logback-XSD/master/src/main/xsd/logback.xsd">

    <appender name="message" class="tld.company.example.MessageClientAppender">
        <levelFormats>
            <!--
                Как здесь использовать атрибуты?
                <levelFormat level="">
            -->
            <levelFormat>
                <level>...</level>
                <messageTemplate>...</messageTemplate>
                <messageFormat>...</messageFormat>
            </levelFormat>
        </levelFormats>
    </appender>

    <logger name="tld.company.example" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="message" />
    </logger>

    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

###### CustomAppender.java

```java
public class CustomAppender extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> {

    private final List<LevelFormat> levelFormats = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public List<LevelFormat> getLevelFormats() {
        return levelFormats;
    }
    public void setLevelFormats( final List<LevelFormat> levelFormat ) {
        if( levelFormat != null ) {
            this.levelFormats.clear();
            this.levelFormats.addAll( levelFormat );
        }
    }
    public void addLevelFormat( final LevelFormat levelFormat ) {
        if( levelFormat != null ) {
            this.levelFormats.add( levelFormat );
        }
    }

    
    @Override protected void append( final ILoggingEvent event ) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

###### LevelFormat.java

```java
public class LevelFormat
{
    private String  messageTemplate;
    private String  messageFormat;
    // не помогает @XmlAttribute(name = "level")
    private Level   level;

    public String getMessageFormat() {
        return messageFormat;
    }
    public void setMessageFormat( final String format ) {
        this.messageFormat = format;
    }

    public String getMessageTemplate() {
        return messageTemplate;
    }
    public void setMessageTemplate( final String template ) {
        this.messageTemplate = template;
    }

    // не помогает @XmlAttribute(name = "level")
    public Level getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
    // не помогает @XmlAttribute(name = "level")
    public void setLevel( final Level level )
    {
        this.level = level;
    }
}
```